# Minified version of XLSX on Angular 5?

Tags: excel, angular, webpack, angular5, xlsx

Is there a correct way to use minified XLSX on an Angular 5 project?

Currently I'm using it as:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

Using this import like:

```
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
```

And

```
const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
```

It works just fine, but produces a very large bundle object inside my build:
[image]

I want to know if it's possible to use the .min files, to help reduce the bundle size. And if so, how to import and use it properly?

Comment: Hi
Is this resolved?

Comment: Actually no. I managed to reduce bundle size by following [developer's suggestions on GitHub](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/1100), to suppress cpexcel.js, but still using non minified versions.

Comment: So you are using this lib, using eject option with Webpack build?

Comment: Yes. Ejecting the 'cpexcel.js' file, to reduce bundle size.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it in Angular:

```js
    import('xlsx').then(xlsx => {});
```

It is triggered only when a user clicks on my excel service button :) It seems like 'bad practice' but the `xlsx` can't really be minified properly.. anyway, it saved me *1.2MB* on my bundle!

Discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/694#issuecomment-688310069

Getting the types requires extra (but yet easy) work - read this: [How to use types with dynamic imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214910/how-to-use-types-with-dynamic-imports)

I was inspired by this developer, who encountered the same problem: https://netbasal.com/using-typescript-dynamic-imports-in-angular-d210547484dd

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

    // import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
    // import { utils, write } from 'xlsx';
    // import { WorkSheet, WorkBook } from 'xlsx';

    const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
    const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class ExcelService {
    
      constructor() { }
    
      public exportAsExcelFile(arrOfObjs: {}[], excelFileName: string): void {
        import('xlsx').then(xlsx => {
          // console.log(xlsx);
          const worksheet: import('xlsx').WorkSheet = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(arrOfObjs);
          console.log('worksheet', worksheet);
          const wb: import('xlsx').WorkBook = { Sheets: { data: worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
          if (!wb.Workbook) { wb.Workbook = {}; }
          if (!wb.Workbook.Views) { wb.Workbook.Views = []; }
          if (!wb.Workbook.Views[0]) { wb.Workbook.Views[0] = {}; }
          wb.Workbook.Views[0].RTL = true;
          const excelBuffer: BlobPart = xlsx.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
          this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
        });
      }
    
      private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: BlobPart, fileName: string): void {
        const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
          type: EXCEL_TYPE
        });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have to change this line from "module": "es2015" to  "module": "esnext" in
tsconfig.json  in order to work with this line

import('xlsx').then(xlsx => {

});

Answer (score -1):

You could use the mini version if you don't need the full functionality.

A slimmer build with XLSX / HTML support is generated at dist/xlsx.mini.min.js.

Instead of

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

use

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/dist/xlsx.mini.min';
```

Comment: I got this error when change import target.  
>error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'xlsx/dist/xlsx.mini.min'.